# external javascript overwrites while I try to insert it into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am able to execute external JS file (which is used to render chemical molecules) inside jQuery.  However, when the external JS file is loaded, it overwrites everything from my initial file.

How am i supposed to insert the external JS file into the appropriate DOM (in this case, the last available class with className "render") without overwriting the existing HTML file?
I use an URL to get data in JSON format and parse it using .each() function as mentioned below.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.get("someURL", function (json){
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
                    $(".container").append("<ul class =\"items\">");
                    $.each(obj, function(i){
                        name = obj[i].name;
                        mol = obj[i].mol;
                        script = $(document.createElement('script')).attr('type', 'text/javascript').attr('src','js/external.js');  
                        $('ul.items').append('<li><div class="render">');
                        $(script).appendTo(".render:last");
                    });
                });
            });
```

My external js file is,

```
            transform = new ChemDoodle.TransformCanvas(name, 150, 150, true);
            transform.loadMolecule(ChemDoodle.readMOL(mol));
```

Also, please note that I have no programming experience and trying to learn JS/jQuery on my own for a couple of months.
Any help/guidance is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Kaushik

I could solve the above problem.
The problem was in the external.js (chemdoodle JS which renders chemical compounds) file that I was using.  It renders chemical compound structure inside .  Due to an inherent problem in chemdoodle's JS component, it used to overwrite my file (irrespective of if I call it as external script or internal function).  I had to explicitly insert  DOM with the same id as the chemdoodle was using.  Here is what I did and that solved the problem.  It might help someone who is working with chemdoodle too!

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    function canvasCall(name, mol){

                        transform = new ChemDoodle.TransformCanvas(name, 150, 150, true);
                        transform.specs.bonds_useJMOLColors = true;
                        transform.specs.set3DRepresentation('Stick');
                        transform.specs.atoms_display = false;
                        transform.specs.backgroundColor = 'black'; 
                        transform.specs.bonds_clearOverlaps_2D = true;        
                        transform.loadMolecule(ChemDoodle.readMOL(mol));

                    };

                    $(".container").append("<ul class =\"items\">");

                    $.getJSON(someURL, function (obj){
                        $.each(obj, function(i){
                        var name = obj[i].name;
                        var mol = obj[i].mol;

                        $('ul.items').append("<li><div class=\"render\"><canvas id=\"" + name + "\">");
                        $("#"+name).append(canvasCall(name, mol));
                    });
                });
            });
```